# JqGrid Overlays with menu

Tags: jqgrid

I have this problem.

[image]

My menu is not showing correctly, the grid is hidding some options.

What could be the problem??

I am using this imports :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="js/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="js/ui.jqgrid.css" />
```

Comment: Please include always **which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). CSS settings (mostly from the files `ui.grid.css`) are **different** in different versions of jqGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

Change the ui.grid.css

Erase the z index: 101 at class .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv
Erase the position:relative in class .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view

Fixed, now it displays correctly